# Oracle with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am trying to connect dropdownlist to bound with oracle 10g when i run the page from VS it works fine but when i run it from IIS it give the following error

`System.Data.OracleClient` requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.

My connection string is

```
<add 
     name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=sml2;Persist Security Info=True;User 
                       ID=sfpl;Password=a;Unicode=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

please solve my problem

Comment: My connection string is  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=sml2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sfpl;Password=a;Unicode=True"
   providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />

Comment: Read this article - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fabdulwahab/archive/2011/11/13/system-data-oracleclient-requires-oracle-client-software-version-8-1-7-or-greater.aspx and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/a442feec-a96a-47f3-946c-f4f2767664d4/

Comment: No dear i already read these articles but the problem is same please tell me some thing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Providers for ASP.NET support this service provider mechanism allowing application state storage within an Oracle database. Existing ASP.NET provider developers will discover the Oracle Providers for ASP.NET are easy to learn and use as they share a common schema and API with existing ASP.NET providers. They integrate seamlessly with existing ASP.NET services and controls, just like other ASP.NET providers.

Oracle offers the following providers:

Membership Provider
Role Provider
Site Map Provider
Session State Provider
Profile Provider
Web Events Provider
Web Parts Personalization Provider
Cache Dependency Provider

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the `Oracle client software` installed.  You also have to make sure `ISUER` or your app pool's identity has permission to the Oracle client directory, same for `TNS` directories and resources.